# How do i retrieve the ConnectionString from app.config file for entity framework without getting a null reference exception

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, app-config

I want to retrieve the `ConnectionString` from the `app.config` in the DataAccess class library for use in Entity Framework's `.edmx` model of the application by using this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace BusinessLogicAndData
{
    public class Connection
    {
        public static RevenueData GetContext()
        {
            //ConfigurationManager configManager = new ConfigurationManager();
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RevenueData"].ConnectionString;

            RevenueData RDC = new RevenueData(conString);

            return RDC;
        }
    }
}
```

But each time the program runs, it throws a null reference exception complaining that

> *object reference is not set to an instance of an object*

I have walked through the stack trace of the VS 2010 but I can't seem to pinpoint the problem. Please any suggestions about the origin of the exception.

Comment: @DavidBrabant this the connection string added to the app.config of the dataaccess class library by the edmx file

Comment: @DavidBrabant `<add name="RevenueDataContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ChurchRevenueModel.csdl|res://*/ChurchRevenueModel.ssdl|res://*/ChurchRevenueModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=OGBONNA-HP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=ChurchRevenue;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add connection string to `App.Config` of your executable application (not to config in DataAccess library project).